# Delta issues from a Fortify scan

Tags: java, fortify

I am using Fortify 18.20 to scan my Java codebase. It create a .fpr file containing all issues found. This .fpr file can be opened using Fortify workbench and there are several options to view the issues. I am interested in knowing new issues added in last 1 day, 1 week etc so that we know which issues to be fixed before the release.

However I don't see an option to see new issues in last x days, do you know how can I achieve that?

There is an option to see new issues (not time based) and it shows all issues. Is there a way 2 .fpr files can be compared and delta can be obtained?

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial answer.  An fpr is a zip file (rename .fpr to .zip and you will see what I mean) and contains a file audit.fdvl.  This is an XML file, and FVDL/Vulnerabilities/Vulnerability is an array of the identified vulnerabilities.  You can then compare those two arrays to find out what changed.

Comment: Thanks woody. I will check